# XY Amchart XY chart showing data on hovering perfectly on bullet

Tags: amcharts

How can I show the data in balloon text while cursor is in chart in when using xy type chart?

I want to show my data like this:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/chart-with-gaps-in-data/

I am using type: xy amchart, with x axis values as date, and y axis data as integer .

Answer (score 1):

The amCharts demo uses a `chartCursor` (https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor) for this behavior. Unfortunately you cannot get the same behavior for an XY chart, meaning for an XY chart, balloons will only show when hovering exactly over a data point/bullet.

But if your X-axis is a date based axis and Y is an integer (value) axis, you could use a Serial Chart to get that same `chartCursor` behavior.